# What is the CLI command to display logs of a robot framework test case

Tags: python, robotframework

**temp** is the name of the test case:

```
temp
    Log    Test
```

How to print the below logs onto command prompt?

```
Starting test: MCP.MCP NFR NEW.temp
20180402 18:11:35.557 : TRACE : Arguments: [ 'Test' ]
20180402 18:11:35.557 :  INFO : Test
20180402 18:11:35.557 : TRACE : Return: None
Ending test:   MCP.MCP NFR NEW.temp
```

I have a test case to be run in robot framework from the command prompt. What is the command to print the logs of a RIDE test case on prompt?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to show these messages on the console? What is your reason for having this information shown here? Have you evaluated any other options?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using `Log To Console` keyword present in `Builtin` Library.

```
| Log To Console | Hello, Safdar!
```

[Please check this link for more info](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console) !!!

Comment: **pybot.bat -T -L Trace -d F:/ride_ont_logs --argumentfile c:\users\smirza\appdata\local\temp\RIDEtbtbei.d\argfile.txt --listener C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:55598:False C:\Users\smirza\Desktop\RobotProject\MCP**  is the command to run test case. Is the any such commands to print the log file by issuing a cmd onto command prompt.